# A click event not detected

Tags: jquery, click

As I was suggested by the precedent question, here s the code that doesn t work :

```
    <div class="comments"></div>

    <textarea cols="" rows="" name="proposition" id="propo-textarea-spec"></textarea>

   <button id="my-btn">Make m'y request!</button>

    <div class="my-btn-spec invisible">
        <div class="section">

        <div class="info tag-comment-spec"></div>
            <p class="targetting"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    
        $('#my-btn').click(function() {
            var comment = $('#propo-textarea-spec').val();
    
            $('.targetting:last').text(comment);
        
            var content = $('div.my-btn-spec').html();
            $('div .comments').append(content);

        });


        $('.comments .tag-comment-spec').click(function(){
            alert('hello');
      
        });

    </script>
```

The fact is that the code works fine as to appending the div, but it is impossible to trigger the alert message when clicking on the new appending div. Strangely,my inspector detects correctly the tag-comment-spec div but the click triggers nothing.

Does anybody has an idea ?

Answer (score 4):

As you're appending `.tag-comment-spec` to DOM dynamically to you need delegate event handler using `.on()`.

```
$('.comments').on('click', '.tag-comment-spec', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event handling with dynamic elements is:

```
$(StaticElement).on( eventName, target, handlderFunction);
```

Where, `StaticElement` refers to an element which belong to DOM at page load and contains the `target` element and `target` is the element on which you want to bind event.

**Related refs:**

- jQuery **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery .on function for the appended div, rather than the .click event.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

When you attach the on click function with the alert inside you are only attaching that event handler to currently existing elements matching the passed selector.

You need to use event delegation to attach event handlers to events that may exist down the line. Try:

```
$('.comments').on('click', '.tag-comment-spec', function() {
   alert('hello');
   // Do more stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to have a look at `.live()`. Or, because this is deprecated, `.on()`.
I think the new content has no eventlistener, because the adding of the event listeners is on page load. With `.on()` or `.live()` you don't have this problem.

```
$("#myEl").on("click", dosomething); // live and click are exchangeable here. (Only in syntax. Effectivity may be discussed.)
```